# visual studio 2017 status bar color

Tags: visual-studio-2017

VS2017 has (at least with the newest update I also just installed), at the bottom of the main window, a brightly shining blue status bar, which visually sticks out greatly. As this is the only big bright blue thing on the whole screen, this very distracting.

Is there a way to change the color?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983535/how-to-edit-customize-color-themes-in-vs2017-preview), there is an official theme editor for Visual Studio 2017. You can install it through the menu "Tools > Extensions and updates" and search online source for "Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2017".

It will install an extension which will make you be able to edit each element of a visual style.
You can see more details of that extension on the official [Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.VisualStudio2017ColorThemeEditor) page and also some help steps on [this page from GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-ColorThemes).

In my case, I wanted to change the purple color of the statusbar from the Dark theme and I was able through that extension.

**Update on Feb, 19-2019**

This editor should work on Visual Studio 2019 as well, as can be seen on "*Works with*" section on Visual Studio Marketplace website.

Comment: There's now a specific Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2019. This worked great, thank you.