# How to change status bar color in Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Visual studio has this distracting blue status bar. Anyone know to change this to something a bit more palatable? The previous methods of File -> Preferences don't seem to be there anymore in this version of VS.

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My rep isn't up to 50 yet, so I couldn't comment on your question, but have you seen this:  [visual studio 2017 status bar color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46269896/visual-studio-2017-status-bar-color). Just search "Color Theme Editor" and you'll see the one for 2019. Mine was right at the top. 
Otherwise, I can't find any way except changing the theme... grrr...