# visual studio 2017, javascript Monokai or One Dark Pro theme

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I saw lots of posts how to change the theme to One dark Pro in visual studio code. However after searching for 2 whole hours. I got nothing closer to getting this theme or Monokai within Visual Studio 2017.

Is it possible have anyone done it? If so could you please provide me with a link of how to do it?

Comment: the problem is you want to change the theme of VS2017 to a darker version and don't know how to change theme?

Comment: No that one can be done in the options. And switch to a darker theme. I want to have a specific theme that doesn't ship by default with Visual studio 2017. With other IDE's you jsut download the theme and upload it, however in Visual studio this isn't the case. So I was wondering whether anyone had done it before

Comment: Found those https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40983535/how-to-edit-customize-color-themes-in-vs2017-preview & https://github.com/Microsoft/VS-ColorThemes/tree/master/VSColorThemes/Themes

Comment: I think you are searching for a specific pattern, that exists in Editors and not IDE. VSCode is not as complicated as VS2017, so i don't think you will get it working as it will have to support all the languages that VS2017 does, which are a lot :). Writing a theme, for an editor is simpler, thus why so many exist.

Answer (score 0):

You can import and export .vssettings files, (which includes customised fonts and colours), using the Tools menu in Visual Studio 2017.

Here's a set that someone exported which does a reasonable imitation of Monokai...
https://github.com/hey-mikey/vssettings/blob/master/chris_frewin_monokai.vssettings

Found in the original article...
https://medium.com/@frewin.christopher/how-to-add-awesome-monokai-colors-for-beautiful-c-development-in-visual-studio-2017-a403a2200c25